# Jenkins selenium plugin - how to differentiate nodes using label

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-grid

I have selenium plugin installed in jenkins (comes with selenium grid).I am triggering my selenium scripts to run on nodes with desired capabilities.

Could someone clarify on how to use labels to differentiate nodes as mentioned in the plugin summary

[wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Plugin)

```
DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
// say you use the redhat5 label to indicate RHEL5 and the amd64 label to specify the architecture
capability.setCapability("jenkins.label","redhat5 && amd64");
// Say you want a specific node to thread your request, just specify the node name (it must be running a selenium configuration though)
capability.setCapability("jenkins.nodeName","(master)");
```

how can I set the desired capabilities as above?

All I need is to be able to differentiate which node to run my tests when they have same OS and browser configuration.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's difficult to tell what is being asked here, and this question cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. Please provide the context, and/or post code samples of what you have done (i.e.: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)).

Answer (score 0):

**Follow below steps :**

1. Add a label to your node on the node's **'Configure'** page (`Configure -> Labels`).
2. Then, In your project configuration, you can set it up to run on a specific node by going to `(Your Project)->Configure->Restrict` where this project can be run (tick).
3. Add the label of your node on `'Label Expression'`.

Hope that helps.